# Where can I find open listings of zipcodes in Indonesia?

Tags: data-request, postal-code, asia

In reviewing the data from geonames, I discovered in my spot check that Indonesia is missing.  A bit of time with Google revealed a few places where I could buy data sets but nothing open.

Anywhere where this data is known to be available free of restrictions?

Edit:  It looks like there are a few countries missing.  Singapore is another one that is missing.  There may be others.  I would assume the Singapore postal system can manage if a zipcode is omitted but not sure about other places.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.indonesianewsonline.com/prangko/stamps/kodepos.htm) website claims to contain a *complete [list of?] postal code[s] in Indonesia*

It is not in a good machine readable format, but the html uses `<pre>` tags with makes much more easier script the data off there.